# How to inform the user when php is done saving the file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

after suggestions in this post, I finally made my code worked.

```
$myFile = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$x = $result . "\r\n";
fwrite($fh, $x);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: yes. its already saved but I dont kwno how to inform the user once its done saving the results in the textfile.

Comment: Actually, what I meant was, have you tried anything to inform your user? Just in the end of your file you could add a line like, `echo "Data is saved"; ` etc

Comment: yes php can. when the fwrite() function stops executing it means the data is saved. so just after that statement you can confirm that it's saved in your textfile. Hope this time I've not misunderstood you

Comment: @Fallen, thats what Im asking. can you help me write a snippet how I know if fwrite function stops executing so I can inform the user? sorry Im still noob in php.

Comment: `fwrite()` terminates just after the line. check the answer from Tanvir Chowdhury.

Comment: add `echo "File is saved!";` after `fwrite($fh, $x);` and check what it shows

Comment: @Fallen yes. this is exactly what i want to know. thanks for all your help.

Comment: @anagnam In order to **"track"** if the file has been saved, you can implement it in a form, where the person entering the data, enters their name and email, then the script send you and the user an Email, if that is what you call "tracking" and if that is your actual "goal". All this using an `if/else`. If it's just a simple message to show that the data has been saved, then a plain old-fashion `echo "The data has been saved";` line of code will do the trick.

Comment: @anagnam Plus, the way you have your script set up with the `a` switch, all data previously saved by others, will also be made accessible (to others). In order to write to a file that's to be used only once, use the `w` switch. The `a` or `a+` switch **"appends/adds"** to a file, while `w` **"overwrites"** anything already in a file.

Comment: @fred say i have 2 elements in the array and when i use `w` it sure does overwrite the file but it only write 1 which is the last element instead of 2.

Comment: @anagnam Can you edit your question and **add** the code you are presently using underneath your present code/question, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @anagnam Plus, if you're using a **form** to do this, post that also or make a new question.

Comment: @Fred i have edited my question to show you the modified code. please note that if i use `a`, all the elements of the array are stored in text file but with `w` only the last element is stored.

Comment: @anagnam Is your goal to **add** to your file, or **overwrite** it with new content?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34281/discussion-between-anagnam-and-fred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is sequential. If you tell it to save to a file and then echo afterwords it will do exactly that. It will finish saving to the file and then echo afterwords. But I must ask - could you be executing another separate PHP file inside of your submit function? If so then pseudo code above could very well echo out before the background process of saving the file is completed...

Comment: no. just after fwrite done saving. the file just sits on the server and no more script is running.

Comment: I see. Then you could simply do what your question asks. PHP will naturally write everything and then echo if that is the order you wrote them in :)

Comment: @Fallen I have edited my question to show you my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

after suggestions in this post, I finally made my code worked.

```
$myFile = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$x = $result . "\r\n";
fwrite($fh, $x);
echo "Done Saving!";
fclose($fh);
```